# Convert expression to disjunctive normal form (DNF)

Tags: disjunctive-normal-form

### Problem

Convert following to DNF

$$ p \rightarrow (q \wedge \neg p) $$

### Attempt to convert

$$ p \rightarrow (q \wedge \neg p) $$

$$ \iff \neg p \vee (q \wedge \neg p) $$
$$ \iff q \vee (\neg p \wedge \neg p) $$
$$ \iff q \vee \neg p $$

is this correct?

Comment: No, the two are not equivalent. With valuation $v$ such that $v(q)=v(p) = \text T$ the first one is False while the last one is True.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA $\neg p \vee (q \wedge \neg p) $ would be correct and considered as DNF?

Comment: See [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic) : after 2nd step it must be : $(\lnot p \lor q) \land \lnot p$.

Comment: Yes; see [DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) : "a disjunction of conjunctive clauses".